# How to find multiple horizontal straight lines in a scatter plot using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot, scatter, horizontal-line, straight-line-detection

[image]
Hi,
I have a set of points (scatter plot). I am interested in finding multiple (approximately) horizontal straight lines (or clusters) in this data. For example in the image attached, I have drawn straight lines to show the desired result. Number of total possible straight lines in the data is unknown beforehand.

I shall be really thankful if anyone could tell me how to approach this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the RANSAC algorithm ([see example in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ransac.html))  or the Hough transform ([See example here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html)). Once lines are found, you can set a bound to their slope to select those that are close to being horizontal given some tolerance.